# ETOPO1 region selection (in python)

Tags: oceanography, python, topography

I am trying to select a region in the Mediterranean Sea from the ETOPO1 data.

```
# bathymetry
from netCDF4 import Dataset

data = Dataset("ETOPO1_Bed_g_gdal.grd",'r')
print(data.variables.keys())

# Get data
lon_range = data.variables['x_range'][:]
lat_range = data.variables['y_range'][:]
topo_range = data.variables['z_range'][:]
spacing = data.variables['spacing'][:]
dimension = data.variables['dimension'][:]
z = data.variables['z'][:]
lon_num = dimension[0]
lat_num = dimension[1]

# Prepare array
lon_input = np.zeros(lon_num); lat_input = np.zeros(lat_num)
for i in range(lon_num):
    lon_input[i] = lon_range[0] + i * spacing[0]
for i in range(lat_num):
    lat_input[i] = lat_range[0] + i * spacing[1]

# Create 2D array
lon, lat = np.meshgrid(lon_input, lat_input)

# Convert 2D array from 1D array for z value
topo = np.reshape(z, (lat_num, lon_num))

# Select region
lon_idx_min = np.abs(lon_input-12.6).argmin()
lon_idx_max = np.abs(lon_input-13.4).argmin()
lat_idx_min = np.abs(lat_input-43.8).argmin()
lat_idx_max = np.abs(lat_input-44.2).argmin()

# get data
topo[lon_idx_min:lon_idx_max, lat_idx_min:lat_idx_max].data
```

This returns an empty array:

```
>>array([], shape=(0, 24), dtype=float64)
```

One main questions:

**1 - What I am doing wrong?**
When I check the lon lat values I am slicing (lat_input[lat_idx_max] etc) they make sense. However, lon_idx_max and lon_idx_min are above len(topo) (11556 and 11604 vs 10801). I guess this is the problem, but I cannot find the cause of it.

One bonus question:

2 - Why if I flip lon and lat I get some data? Note that the data do not make sense (-4000ish meters in the Adriatic Sea...)

Comment: hi, where does x_range come from, because when i try to rebuild your example python doesn't know it for me

Comment: when I print the variables of the nc file, it is there along y_range and z_range

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you simply messed up the order of your min and max of the latitude. And you were looking at the wrong place (-44° instead of +44°).

```
# bathymetry
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset

data = Dataset("ETOPO1_Bed_g_gmt4.grd",'r')

lon_range = data.variables['x_range'][:]
lat_range = data.variables['y_range'][:]
topo_range = data.variables['z_range'][:]
spacing = data.variables['spacing'][:]
dimension = data.variables['dimension'][:]
z = data.variables['z'][:]
lon_num = dimension[0]
lat_num = dimension[1]

lon = np.linspace(lon_range[0],lon_range[1],dimension[0])
lat = np.linspace(lat_range[0],lat_range[1],dimension[1])

topo = np.reshape(z, (lat_num, lon_num))

# Select region
lon_idx_min = np.abs(lon-10).argmin() # I increased the margin a little
lon_idx_max = np.abs(lon-20).argmin() # to better see where the region is
lat_idx_min = np.abs(lat+48).argmin()
lat_idx_max = np.abs(lat+40).argmin()

plt.imshow(topo[lat_idx_min:lat_idx_max, lon_idx_min:lon_idx_max], vmax=0)
```

By using np.linspace you can remove the loop from your code and speed it up significantly.
There is no need to create a meshgrid from lat and lon.

Comment: greetings fellow meteorologist