# World Elevation Data as CSV

Tags: models

Hi I need For each Lat and Long value also the Alt value! However, I am having problems extracting these values from a Geotiff and wonder if this data is publicly available in Excel or CSV file format? Unfortunately I have not found anything myself!

my data: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/8e5ba7aa4cd8c406068a60543b353b0420220622084939/d3c744
For people who know Python:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import pandas as pd

data = Dataset("C:/Users/Oliver Weisser/Desktop/Bachelor/Programm/Daten/Daten/ETOPO1_Bed_g_gdal.grd",'r')
print(data.variables.keys())

lon_range = data.variables['x_range'][:]
lat_range = data.variables['y_range'][:]
topo_range = data.variables['z_range'][:]
spacing = data.variables['spacing'][:]
dimension = data.variables['dimension'][:]
z = data.variables['z'][:]
lon_num =  dimension[0]
lat_num =  dimension[1]

lon = np.linspace(lon_range[0],lon_range[1],dimension[0])
lat = np.linspace(lat_range[0],lat_range[1],dimension[1])

topo = np.reshape(z, (lat_num, lon_num))


dfl = pd.DataFrame({
        'Latitude': lat.reshape(-1),
        'Longitude': lon.reshape(-1),
        'Altitude': topo.reshape(-1)
        })
print(dfl)
```

Source: [ETOPO1 region selection (in python)](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/23904/etopo1-region-selection-in-python/23924#23924)

This is the code I have written so far, maybe someone will find a bug there

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137302/discussion-on-question-by-weiss-world-elevation-data-as-csv).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I hope I finally understood what your problem really was and this gives you the height information at your specific lat lon values from your csv data.

```
import numpy as np
from netCDF4 import Dataset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

csv_data = np.loadtxt('1994_12_O18grid.csv',skiprows=1,delimiter=',')

num_el = csv_data[:,0]
lat = csv_data[:,1]
lon = csv_data[:,2]
value = csv_data[:,3]

data = Dataset("ETOPO1_Bed_g_gdal.grd",'r')
lon_range = data.variables['x_range'][:]
lat_range = data.variables['y_range'][:]
topo_range = data.variables['z_range'][:]
spacing = data.variables['spacing'][:]
dimension = data.variables['dimension'][:]
z = data.variables['z'][:]
lon_num =  dimension[0]
lat_num =  dimension[1]

etopo_lon = np.linspace(lon_range[0],lon_range[1],dimension[0])
etopo_lat = np.linspace(lat_range[0],lat_range[1],dimension[1])
topo = np.reshape(z, (lat_num, lon_num))

height = np.empty_like(num_el)
for i in range(len(num_el)):  #in this loop we search for the height values for the specific lat and lon values from your csv
    desired_lat_idx = np.abs(etopo_lat - lat[i]).argmin()
    desired_lon_idx = np.abs(etopo_lon - lon[i]).argmin()
    height[i] = topo[desired_lat_idx,desired_lon_idx]

plt.figure()
height[height<0]=0 # if you want to disregard values below 0
plt.imshow(np.reshape(height,(180,360))) # if the resolution of your csv data changes from 1 degree to something different you need to chance the values in the reshape. For simplicity I hardcoded the numbers.
```

The searching for the height levels is not that efficient but I didnt have the time to do a proper numpy style solution.

Comment: I will have a detailed look at it! but it looks very promising! Thank you very much for your time and for answering me so patiently!

Comment: You are welcome, maybe as an advice in the future try to better formulate your issues and questions. Then people can help you more quickly :)

Comment: OK I will do that! You may notice that I am new to coding and still need some help :-)

Comment: Yeah, no worries. Everyone started at one point.

Comment: Hi @smichel I'm afraid I don't quite understand the probgram and I still want to ask how I can extract the data from this figure that I have a table that looks like this: Long/lat/Value(CSV)/Altitude? If something is unclear, I will try to ask the question again in more detail in a new question.

Comment: I now managed to save the data as I want, however the data are upside down, how can I change it?